# Asp.Net Datagrid view is not updating on new insertion

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Well As the title explains it all so here is the code i used so far

```
public partial class data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con3;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds1;
    DataTable dt;
    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con3 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con3.ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost; initial catalog=test;user id=xx;password=xxxx;";
        con3.Open();
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd3.CommandText = "selectdata";
        cmd3.Connection = con3;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd3);
        da.Fill(ds1, "abc");
        con3.Close();
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds1.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Stored Procedure is

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectdata] 
AS
BEGIN
    select * from data
END
```

i searched stack overflow & did search on Google but nothing happened.
i tried closing connection after data bind, defining a new data set & creating the table again & much more please help

Comment: Probably your stored procedure is wrong.

Comment: can you share stored procedure

Comment: i don't think so. because if the stored procedure was wrong than there should be no data at all in grid view. all i am asking is " i want gridview to be refreshed upon new insertion.

Comment: @Mehdi question updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer Above just refresh the page so in my view it should be

1--> Define A Function & bind data in this such as

```
private void bind_data()
    {
        ASPxGridLookup2.DataSource = dt_employee;
        ASPxGridLookup2.DataBind();
        ASPxGridLookup3.DataSource = dt_attendance;
        ASPxGridLookup3.DataBind();
        ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt_attendance;
        ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

2--> Call this function whenever you need to refresh the datagrid such as right after insertion

```
obj2.insertion();
       bind_data();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the page after insertion.

Comment: but i wanted to do it without pressing f5 :P anyhow thanks for your answer, i have found my way :)